# .mdf equivalent for mysql (TOAD)

Tags: mysql, recovery, toad

What is 'SQL Server Database Primary Data File (.mdf)' equivalent for mysql.

- I am using 'Toad for mysql' (Vesion 7.7) tool

Answer (score 1):

MYSQL usually comes with MyISAM/INNODB databases.

For MyISAM the files are:

`.MYD` for data files
`.MYI` for index files
`.frm` for table format files

InnoDB uses a single container file for the data and `.frm` for the definition and `.ibd` for the indexes.

Are you trying to load data from SQL Server .MDF into MySQL DB? In simple words are you tring to migrate from SQL server to MYSql?

Regards.

Comment: Thanks for quick response. Actualy my hard disk is crashed but still able to find .frm,myi and .myd files in C drive but I am not able to find procedures.

Comment: That is not try for InnoDB. InnoDB uses a single container file for the data and .frm for the definition and .ibd for the indexes.

Comment: Thank you for the information @a_horse_with_no_name. I will update my answer accordingly.